# How to stop a timer running inside a class C#

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer running inside a class. I have two push buttons.
Push button 1 is to start the timer(which is inside a class)
Push button 2 is to stop the timer forcefully.
Timer runs smoothly when click on push button 1 and perform calculations.
But when I press Push button 2 the timer does not stopped forcefully and throws an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred ".

Note:if I use public static System.Timers.Timer theTimer1; then timer could be stopped with push button 2.But I dont want to use static and when if condition will be true then it stopped automatically but stop method is not working with push button.
How can I stop this timer with push button.
Thanks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();             
    } 

    Test acc = new Test();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        acc.SerialPortEvent()
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        acc.stop();
    }
}

class Test
{
    public System.Timers.Timer theTimer1;

    public void SerialPortEvent()
    {
        theTimer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        theTimer1.Elapsed += timer_Tick;
        theTimer1.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform some calculations here.
        if (something like counter)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        theTimer1.Stop();
        theTimer1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line number is throwing the exception?

Comment: exception is throwing at theTimer1.Stop();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely that you're trying to stop your Timer from a *different thread*

So let's assume that you are in thread 1 and you create a reference to your timer that is instantiated in thread 2. After some time thread 1 has ended and you are in thread 3 where you're trying to reach that reference from thread 1. That's why you got null reference exception.

You should either use static, volatile or Task and Task Cancellation Token.

```
public volatile System.Timers.Timer theTimer1;
```

Comment: I have used Static and I can stop the timer with press button.But I am using this test class simultaneously for another calculations. So when i use static then it creates some problem by same class at two locations.

Comment: Use Task and Cancellation Token or at least add a 'volatile' keyword to your Timer - by adding this keyword you let the compiler know that your field can be accessed from a different threads.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the timer in the constructor of `Test`:

```
class Test
{
   public Test()
   {
       theTimer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
   }
```

Your code initializes the timer only when `SerialPortEvent()` is called.

This is not called until you press the `Start` button, hence you get a null reference exception when you press `Stop` without pressing `Start` first.

Furthermore your `stop()` function disposes the timer. This might be an issue when you try to stop the timer after it was disposed.

Comment: Thank you @thumbmunkeys . I got you point.But I am unable to stop the timer after starting it with press button.

Comment: does your code set the timer to `null` at some point? (in `stop()` for example)

Comment: I have tried it but it throws exception at theTimer1.Stop();. Before disposing it.